# jquery .each function to check another selector and delete duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

---

I have a jquery datatable that contains name and count data.

```
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th class="count">Count</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            <tbody>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>               
              <td class= "name"><%# Eval("Name") %></td>
              <td class= "count"><%# Eval("count") %></td>             
            </tr>
```

The issue i am facing is trying to retrieve data that matches a certain criteria based on **2 selectors**. For instance, how would i write a jquery function to retrieve names that are "john" and have a count of 4? I am able to retrieve positions where all names that are john as follows:

```
 $('td').each(function () {        
         var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);
         var aData = oTable.fnGetData(aPos[0]);
         var retrievedEntry = aData[aPos[1]];

         if (retrievedEntry == "john") {
             alert($(this).html() + "found at position " + aPos);
         }
 });
```

I tried `alert($(this).find(".count").filter(":contains("1")"));` as a test but keep getting null values.

Also once the data is retrieved, how would i delete all the duplicates and jus leave one record? Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the cells that contain "john", and then filter that result to only contain the ones that have "4" in the next element:

```
$('td.name:contains(john)').filter(function(){ return $(this).next().text() == '4'; })
```

Note: The `:contains` selector makes a partial match, so it would also match for example "johnny". If that is a problem, you would put that check in the filter also:

```
$('td.name').filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == 'john' && $(this).next().text() == '4'; })
```

Comment: Any suggestion on how to go about deleting the duplicates now?

Comment: You would filter out the first item, get the table row for each item, and remove them: `.slice(1).closest('tr').remove()`.

Answer (score 0):

1) You are using **double-quotes** inside and outside of the selector. Consider:    `':contains("1")'`

2) You need to specify selectors one-by-one **without spaces**

```
'.count:contains("1")'
```

Comment: didn't seem to make a difference but Guffa's solution seemed to do the trick. Thanks though